# default multimedia image is showing 404 for dxa 2.2 and sites 9.1

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1

i am using DXA 2.2 application with .net and sites 9.1
i have used Download schema to create multimedia components [zip] and attached them in parent component.

[image]

then parent component has been added to the page and page has been published.

when try to browse the page, zip file url is formed like below: us-en/Images/autopublish-deployer-extension-assembly_tcm6-1000.zip

but onclick of link its shows 404 error.

i have checked following:

1. **Binary data folder**: it does not have any images folder. not sure why folder is not get created.
2. **publication properties for image url**: /us-en/Images/
3. **in dxa application model code** :

   [SemanticProperty("c:imagePackageStandard")]

   public MultimediaSchema ImagePackageStandard { get; set; }

**MultimediaSchema.cs is as follows**

```
[SemanticEntity(CoreVocabulary, "DefaultMultimediaSchema")]
    [Serializable]
    public class MultimediaSchema : MediaItem
    {
        public override string ToHtml(string widthFactor, double aspect = 0, string cssClass = null, int containerSize = 0)
        {
            return string.Format("{1}", Url);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the default View.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="localization">The context Localization</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This makes it possible possible to render "embedded" Image Models using the Html.DxaEntity method.
        /// </remarks>
        public override MvcData GetDefaultView(Localization localization)
        {
            return new MvcData("Core:Download");
        }
    }
```

Broker has binary data that means publishing has no issue.

Any help or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Your `MultimediaSchema.ToHtml` implementation looks quite peculiar/wrong. It is supposed to return HTML, not just a URL (and your don't need `string.Format` to return just a URL :-)  But that's not the cause of this issue, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that the `DxaStaticContentModule` was disabled in `web.config`.  This DXA HTTP Module is essential for handling requests for Static Content Items (incl. Media Items).

Comment: thank you Rick Pannekoek